# If range() is a generator in Python 3.3, why can I not call next() on a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, typeerror

Perhaps I've fallen victim to misinformation on the web, but I think it's more likely just that I've misunderstood something.  Based on what I've learned so far, range() is a generator, and generators can be used as iterators.  However, this code:

```
myrange = range(10)
print(next(myrange))
```

gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

What am I missing here?  I was expecting this to print 0, and to advance to the next value in `myrange`.  I'm new to Python, so please accept my apologies for the rather basic question, but I couldn't find a good explanation anywhere else.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13054057/395760 for the distinction between iterators and things which you can iterate over in a `for` loop.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that generators are iterables, but not iterators?

Comment: @Jeff Iterables are objects that `iter` can be used on to obtain an iterator. Iterators are objects that can be iterated through using `next`. Generators is a category of iterators (generator functions and generator expressions). At least that's what I think...

Answer (score 172, accepted):

`range` is a class of immutable iterable objects. Their iteration behavior can be compared to `list`s: you can't call `next` directly on them; you have to get an iterator by using `iter`.

So no, `range` is not a generator.

You may be thinking, "why didn't they make it an iterator"? Well, `range`s have some useful properties that wouldn't be possible that way:

- They are immutable, so they can be used as dictionary keys.
- They have the `start`, `stop` and `step` attributes (since Python 3.3), `count` and `index` methods and they support `in`, `len` and `__getitem__` operations.
- You can iterate over the same `range` multiple times.

---

```
>>> myrange = range(1, 21, 2)
>>> myrange.start
1
>>> myrange.step
2
>>> myrange.index(17)
8
>>> myrange.index(18)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 18 is not in range
>>> it = iter(myrange)
>>> it
<range_iterator object at 0x7f504a9be960>
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
3
>>> next(it)
5
```

Comment: Another nice feature of `range` objects is that they have a `__contains__` method which can be used to test whether a value is in a range: `5 in range(10) => True`

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this makes sense now.  The only thing I want to clear up before accepting your answer is the note in italics about a third of the way down [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) page, that states that "in Python 3 range() is a generator".  Is this simply incorrect?

Comment: @Jeff Strictly speaking, yes, it is wrong. The author of the note probably meant that in Python 3 `range` is *lazy* (compared to Python 2 where it's just a function that returns a list).

Comment: Also: `range(0,10,3)[3]` and `9 in range(0,10,3)`. Range is pretty much a lazy list.

Comment: One of the final puzzle pieces falls into place...great answer.

Comment: What is the link between being immutable and not being directly iterable? Even an iterable object seems immutable to me so what exactly is the benefit of or reason behind a range object not being directly iterable?

Comment: @user3079275 "directly iterable" is a misnomer, actually meaning "iterator". Iterators have internal state and so are mutable by definition. "Iterable" is an object, whether it is mutable or not, that can produce an iterator. Even mutable objects aren't usually iterators themselves, instead they produce iterators in a reusable manner (for example, you can iterate over the same list in two different places independently, using two iterators).