# Python range() and zip() object type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, range

I understand how functions like `range()` and `zip()` can be used in a for loop. However I expected `range()` to output a list - much like `seq` in the unix shell. If I run the following code:

```
a=range(10)
print(a)
```

The output is `range(10)`, suggesting it's not a list but a different type of object. `zip()` has a similar behaviour when printed, outputting something like

```
<zip object at "hexadecimal number">
```

So my question is what are they, what advantages are there to making them this, and how can I get their output to lists without looping over them?

Comment: Looks like Python 3. Use `a = list(range(10))`.

Comment: In addition to the good answers here, I recommend reading the answer to [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1599111) to learn about generators - an excellent example for why your functions might not want to return a list... just yet.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You must be using Python 3.

In Python 2, the objects `zip` and `range` did behave as you were suggesting, returning lists.  They were changed to [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)-like objects which produce the elements on demand rather than expand an entire list into memory.  One advantage was greater efficiency in their typical use-cases (e.g. iterating over them).

The "lazy" versions also exist in Python 2.x, but they have different names i.e. `xrange` and `itertools.izip`.

To retrieve all the output at once into a familiar list object, you may simply call `list` to iterate and consume the contents:

```
>>> list(range(3))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(zip(range(3), 'abc'))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: While these objects are *lazy* I think it is mis-leading to describe them as like generators, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/if-range-is-a-generator-in-python-3-3-why-can-i-not-call-next-on-a-range

Comment: @Chris_Rands  They are like generators in the most important sense, that elements are produced on demand.  I think my description is fair; I was careful not to actually call them generators, and the differences are not important for this question.

Comment: True, perhaps the tone of my first comment was unfair, sorry, still I'll leave it there because the link provides some further details on range objects for those that are interested

Comment: zip is an iterator:

>>> z = zip((1,2),(3,4))
>>> next(z)
(1, 3)

Answer (score 28):

In Python 3.x., [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#range) returns a range object instead of a list like it did in Python 2.x.  Similarly, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) now returns a zip object instead of a list.

To get these objects as lists, put them in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#list):

```
>>> range(10)
range(0, 10)
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> zip('abc', 'abc')
<zip object at 0x01DB7120>
>>> list(zip('abc', 'abc'))
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
>>>
```

While it may seem unhelpful at first, this change in the behavior of `range` and `zip` actually increases efficiency.  This is because the zip and range objects produce items as they are needed, instead of creating a list to hold them all at once.  Doing so saves on memory consumption and improves operation speed.

Answer (score 7):

Range (`xrange` in python 2.*) objects are [immutable sequences](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types), while zip (`itertools.izip` repectively) is a [generator object](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). To make a list from a generator or a sequence, simply cast to list. For example:

```
>>> x = range(10) 
>>> list(x)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But they differ in a way how elements are generated. Normal generators are mutable and exaust their content if iterated, while range is immutable, and don't:

```
>>> list(x) # x is a range-object
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # second cast to list, contents is the same
>>> y = zip('abc', 'abc')
>>> list(y) # y is a generator
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
>>> list(y) 
[] # second cast to list, content is empty!
```

Comment: I was playing with these examples at the REPL, following earlier answers to this question. When I first consumed my generator-not-generator produced by zip, I was a bit :facepalm: until I read your mention that the second cast to list would result in empty content. Thank you for this!

Comment: I get the error that a list isn't callable when trying to print a zip object in list()