# How to convert a list to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am newbie to Python and need to convert a list to dictionary. I know that we can convert a list of tuples to a dictionary.

This is the input list:

```
L = [1,term1, 3, term2, x, term3,... z, termN]
```

and I want to convert this list to a list of tuples (or directly to a dictionary) like this:

```
[(1, term1), (3, term2), (x, term3), ...(z, termN)]
```

How can we do that easily in Python?

Comment: for dict you can simply use `dict(zip(*[iter(L)]*2))`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
>>> L = [1, "term1", 3, "term2", 4, "term3", 5, "termN"]
# Create an iterator
>>> it = iter(L)
# zip the iterator with itself
>>> zip(it, it)
[(1, 'term1'), (3, 'term2'), (4, 'term3'), (5, 'termN')]
```

You want to group three items at a time?

```
>>> zip(it, it, it)
```

You want to group N items at a time?

```
# Create N copies of the same iterator
it = [iter(L)] * N
# Unpack the copies of the iterator, and pass them as parameters to zip
>>> zip(*it)
```

Comment: Could someone explain what `zip` is doing in this context?  I thought I understood how it works but apparently not, since this doesn't give `[(1,1,1),('term1','term1','term1'),...]`

Comment: @user1717828 every time you access the iterator it advances the position. Zip is pairing two things, taken from the same iterator here. If you wrote `zip(iter(L), iter(L), iter(L))` it would do that, but by breaking out the iter creation and sharing it you get this behaviour.

Comment: This will work in python2, but in python3, you actually need to put the `zip` object in a `list` like so: `list(zip(it,it))` as python3 does not evaluate the `zip` unless you explicitly ask for it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777642

Comment: wow, at first didn't understand what you did there, but now I'm amazed at how simple and beautiful your solution is

Comment: Well, `zip` internally / implicit converts `list` to `iter` and using `next` on it?

Answer (score 18):

Try with the group clustering idiom:

```
zip(*[iter(L)]*2)
```

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html:

> The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.
>   This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into
>   n-length groups using zip(*[iter(s)]*n).

Comment: Ok, I think I understood your code, It is same as @thefourtheye's answer except you use `* 2` to make two copies. I can also write is as `zip(*(iter(L),) * 2)`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, it is a shortened form of the same solution

Comment: Thanks, its very interesting that your code is just 17 bytes long :)

Comment: Very elegant and idiomatic solution. Thanks!

Comment: "The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed" upvote for the explanation quote.. I finally get how this works despite using it many times!! each time the iterator is "evaluated" it is "advanced" to the next element. Thats how/why we get the next element as the second element of the tuple. It's so obvious now!

Answer (score 12):

List directly into a dictionary using `zip` to pair consecutive even and odd elements:

```
m = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] 
d = { x : y for x, y in zip(m[::2], m[1::2]) }
```

or, since you are familiar with the tuple -> dict direction:

```
d = dict(t for t in zip(m[::2], m[1::2]))
```

even:

```
d = dict(zip(m[::2], m[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 10):

Using slicing?

```
L = [1, "term1", 2, "term2", 3, "term3"]
L = zip(L[::2], L[1::2])

print L
```

Comment: This is great. simple, and easy to understand since it's slicing

Answer (score 5):

Try this ,

```
>>> L = [1, "term1", 3, "term2", 4, "term3", 5, "termN"]
>>> it = iter(L)
>>> [(x, next(it)) for x in it ]
[(1, 'term1'), (3, 'term2'), (4, 'term3'), (5, 'termN')]
>>>
```

### OR

```
>>> L = [1, "term1", 3, "term2", 4, "term3", 5, "termN"]
>>> [i for i in zip(*[iter(L)]*2)]
[(1, 'term1'), (3, 'term2'), (4, 'term3'), (5, 'termN')]
```

### OR

```
>>> L = [1, "term1", 3, "term2", 4, "term3", 5, "termN"]
>>> map(None,*[iter(L)]*2)
[(1, 'term1'), (3, 'term2'), (4, 'term3'), (5, 'termN')]
>>>
```

Comment: A good solution if you want to edit an item while iterating!

Answer (score 4):

```
[(L[i], L[i+1]) for i in xrange(0, len(L), 2)]
```

Comment: Hey getting, 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ab.py", line 105, in <module>
    print [(L[i], L[i+1]) for i in xrange(0, len(L), 2)]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @trex you are trying with odd length `L`, according to your question I think you should have even length `L` this will work on Python2.X in Python3.x you should use range instead of xrange

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I am using python2.7, so I use xrange. in python2, xrange is a generator and range returns a list. for a big number n, python2's range(n) will consume many memory. In python3, range is the generator, and xrange no more exists.

Comment: XingFei yes I understand the issue I just means to respond @trex to suggest how to make it execute without error.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will take care of both even and odd sized list :

```
[set(L[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(L),2)]
```