# How to flatten a list of nested tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, flatten

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), (('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'))]
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i')]
```

What is the most Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since he wants to keep the pairs

Comment: Indeed, I retracted the flag

Comment: yes, I want to keep the pairs. I can do this easily with some if statements  in a for-loop, but I'm wondering if there is a better way using either list comprehension or iterators

Comment: You could flatten the whole thing, then pair up the remains: `zip(*[iter(L)]*2)` from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23286332/4834

Comment: Are there any further levels of nesting? Do you only have pairs of values?

Comment: Only two levels of nesting. Thank you all for the great answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one-line, using list comprehension:

```
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), (('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'))]

result = [z for y in (x if isinstance(x[0],tuple) else [x] for x in l) for z in y]

print(result)
```

yields:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i')]
```

this is artificially creating a list if the element is not a tuple of tuples, then flattening all does the job. To avoid creating a single element list `[x]`, `(x for _ in range(1))` can also do the job (although it appears clunky)

Limitation: doesn't handle more than 1 level of nesting. In which case, a more complex/recursive solution must be coded (check [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431859/6451573)).

Answer (score 5):

Adjust the [canonical un-flatten recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) to only unflatten when there are tuples in the value:

```
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, tuple) and any(isinstance(sub, tuple) for sub in el):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
```

This will only unwrap tuples, and only if there are other tuples in it:

```
>>> sample = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), (('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'))]
>>> list(flatten(sample))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i')]
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-line solution would be using `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), (('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'))]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [*chain.from_iterable(x if isinstance(x[0], tuple) else [x] for x in l)]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i')]
```

Comment: Ditto here: This will not handle arbitrary nesting, of course.