# Remove parantheses inside tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, strip

I have a list of tuples:

```
listoftuples = [(('elementone', 'elementtwo'), 'elementthree')(....
```

Now I want to output this list as:

```
listoftuples = [('elementone', 'elementtwo', 'elementthree')(....
```

How can i remove those extra parantheses?
I have tried to strip them put that doesn't work.

Comment: Don't think of it as removing parentheses; you aren't manipulating a string.

Comment: it's unclear what your objects are. Your syntax is incorrect `'elementthree')(....`

Comment: or that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431752/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-nested-tuples-in-python. It's so unclear putting all 3 dupe links will do

Answer (score 1):

If the depth is 2, then you can use itertools:

```
import itertools
listoftuples = [(('elementone', 'elementtwo'), 'elementthree')]
final_list = [tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i] if not isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in b)) for b in listoftuples]
```

Output:

```
[('elementone', 'elementtwo', 'elementthree')]
```

However, with arbitrary depth, it is best to use recursion:

```
def flatten(s):
   if not isinstance(s, tuple):
      yield s
   else:
      for b in s:
          for i in flatten(b):
              yield i


listoftuples = [(('elementone', 'elementtwo'), 'elementthree')]
final_list = map(tuple, map(flatten, listoftuples))
```

Output:

```
[('elementone', 'elementtwo', 'elementthree')]
```