# Flatten Nested Tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, some of which are nested:

```
[(name,(6,9.0,2.4),link),(name,(7.8,9.0,5),link)...]
```

I would like to un-nest the inner tuple for each item in the list, but preserve the outer tuple:

```
[(name,6,9.0,2.4,link),(name,7.8,9.0,5,link)...]
```

This is different from the solution to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431752/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-nested-tuples-in-python) in which the solution sought to preserve the pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
lst = [('xyz',(6,9.0,2.4),'link1'),('abc',(7.8,9.0,5),'link2')]
```

Iterate over `lst` and [unpack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) the inner tuples into the outer tuples. You can do this with a list comprehension.

```
>>> [(x, *y, z) for x, y, z in lst]
[('xyz', 6, 9.0, 2.4, 'link1'), ('abc', 7.8, 9.0, 5, 'link2')]
```

Works on python3.6. For older versions, use tuple concatenation:

```
>>> [(x,) + y + (z,) for x, y, z in lst]
[('xyz', 6, 9.0, 2.4, 'link1'), ('abc', 7.8, 9.0, 5, 'link2')]
```