# Function that transforms a list in a list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, loops, dictionary

I have to make a function whose purpose is taking in parameter a list.

Such as this one :

```
['music', ' extension=mp3', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131', ' max_size=100000', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132', ' max_size=100000', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000']
```

And return a list similar to this :

```
data_config = [{'music' : {'extension':'mp3'}}, {'reports/INFOB131': {'extension': ['doc', 'docx','pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB131', 'max_size':100000}}, {'reports/INFOB132': {'extension': ['doc', 'docx','pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB132', 'max_size':100000}}]
```

So I made that function :

```
def my_function(list_in_question, my_config_list =[], prev_list = []):
    """ """
    enumerated_list = list(enumerate(list_in_question))

    if not '=' in enumerated_list[0][1]:
        main_key = enumerated_list[0][1]# référencé avant assignement
        pre_dict = {main_key : {}}


        for i in enumerated_list[1:]:

            if '=' in i[1] :
                splitted = i[1].split('=')
                prev_list.append({splitted[0] : splitted[1]})

            elif not '=' in i[1] and i[1] != main_key:
                for j in prev_list:
                    pre_dict[main_key].update(j)

                my_config_list.append(pre_dict)

                return my_function(list_in_question[i[0]:])

            elif not '=' in i[1] and i[1] == main_key and main_key!= enumerated_list[0][1]:
                return my_config_list
    else:
        print("The format of the file containig the data in not adequate !")
```

But I don't understand why when I execute it this way :

```
new_lines = ['music', ' extension=mp3', '', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131', ' max_size=100000', '', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132', ' max_size=100000', '', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', '', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', '', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000']

my_function(new_lines)
```

I end up with this output...

```
None
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me,

Thank you !

PS : If anyone have an idea of how I could do without loop and do it in a recursive way, it would be awesome !

Everyone... Thank you !!! You really hepled me, all your answers are awesome, I have some issues to understand some parts so I'll be annoying just a little longer with some questions of you code. Anyway, thank you for the time you took to help me, you were all more than great help !!!

Comment: Finish your function with a `return my_config_list` to, well, return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code;

```
def foo(my_list):
    # Create an iterator
    list_iter = iter(my_list)
    # zip the iterator with itself
    key_val_tuple = zip(list_iter, list_iter) # This will group two items in the list at a time
    output_list = []
    for i in key_val_tuple:
        value_dict = {}
        value = i[1].split('=')
        value_dict[value[0]] = value[1].split(",") if len(value[1].split(","))>1 else value[1]
        element_dict = {}
        element_dict[i[0]] = value_dict
        output_list.append(element_dict)
    return output_list

input_list = ['music', ' extension=mp3', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131', ' max_size=100000', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132', ' max_size=100000', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000']

# Call the function foo
output = foo(input_list)
print(output) # python3
```

Got the following output

> [{'music': {' extension': 'mp3'}}, {'reports/INFOB131': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf']}}, {' name_contains=INFOB131': {' max_size': '100000'}}, {'reports/INFOB132': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf']}}, {' name_contains=INFOB132': {' max_size': '100000'}}, {'games': {' name_contains': ['SC2', 'Wesnoth']}}, {'pictures/Namur': {' extension': 'jpeg'}}, {' min_size=5000000': {' name_contains': 'cercle'}}, {'pictures/autres': {' extension': 'jpeg'}}]

- `zip(list_iter, list_iter)` : This will group two items in the list at a time.

  output : [('music', ' extension=mp3'), ('reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf'), ...]

Reference:

- [python zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)
- [What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)
- [Convert List to a list of tuples python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286254/convert-list-to-a-list-of-tuples-python)

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked perfectly !!! Just a question, could you explain me the use of the zip() and iter() ?

Comment: Please see the updated answer with proper comments and reference links. Let me know if you have any doubts still..

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse the list one time. The pattern is this:

1. Start an empty list (let's call it new_list)
2. You find an element in the original list (original_list).
3. If it does not contain '=', you create a new dictionary in the new_list
4. If it contains the '=' sign, split the element into k and v (before and after the '='), and in the last entry in the new_list, for the only key, you add a key-value pair

   ```
   def parse_list(original_list):
       new_list=[]

       for element in original_list:
           if not '=' in element:
               new_list.append({element:{}})
           else:
               k,w=element.split('=')
               new_list[-1][new_list[-1].keys()[0]][k]=w
       return new_list

   new_lines = ['music', ' extension=mp3', '', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131', ' max_size=100000', '', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132', ' max_size=100000', '', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', '', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', '', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg', ' min_size=5000000']

   parse_list(new_lines)
   ```

Now I should explain the line before the return statement:

- new_list[-1] is the dictionary corresponding to the last entry without an equal sign that was found in the original_list. After the first pass through the loop,

  > new_list=[{'music': {}}]
- during the second pass

  > new_list[-1]={'music': {}}
  >
  > new_list[-1].keys()=['music']
  >
  > new_list[-1].keys()[0]='music'
  >
  > new_list[-1][new_list[-1].keys()[0]]={}
- now you just update this dictionary with the parsed k,w pair

Comment: thank you for your help, if you could just help me to understand this line : new_list[-1][new_list[-1].keys()[0]][k]=w , why [-1] and what does .keys() do ?

Comment: [-1] is the index of the last element in a list. somelist[-1] the same as somelist[len(somelist)-1]. The keys() function return the keys from the dictionary. {'extension': ['doc', 'docx','pdf'], 'name_contains':'INFOB131', 'max_size':100000}.keys() should return ['max_size', 'name_contains', 'extension']. I know that you main dictionaries contain only one key word (for example 'music') so I grabbed the first (and only) element in that list, so I can access the value (the dictionary with all other key-value pairs)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another try with only lists and dicts:

```
def make(lst):
    data_config=[]
    for st in lst:
        if '=' not in st:            # new entry
            dd = dict()
            dds = dd[st] = dict()
            data_config.append(dd)            
        else:                        # fill entry
            k,v = st.split('=')
            if ',' in v:
                v = v.split(',')
            dds[k] = v          
    return data_config
```

For :

```
In [564]: make(l)
Out[564]: 
[{'music': {' extension': 'mp3'}},
 {'reports/INFOB131': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
   ' max_size': '100000',
   ' name_contains': 'INFOB131'}},
 {'reports/INFOB132': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
   ' max_size': '100000',
   ' name_contains': 'INFOB132'}},
 {'games': {' name_contains': ['SC2', 'Wesnoth']}},
 {'pictures/Namur': {' extension': 'jpeg',
   ' min_size': '5000000',
   ' name_contains': 'cercle'}},
 {'pictures/autres': {' extension': 'jpeg', ' min_size': '5000000'}}]
```

Comment: Awesome and easily understandable ! I'm a beginner so this seems perfect to me !

Comment: so check it ;) .

Answer (score 1):

One more way of doing it:

```
import re

def my_function(list_in_question, my_config_list=[], prev_list=[]):
    """ """
    result = {}
    main_key = ''

    for element in list_in_question:
        if element == '':
            main_key = ''
        if re.search('=', element):
            key, value = element.split('=')
            print "key, value = ", key, value
            if re.search(',', value):
                value_list = value.split(',')
                print "value list =", value_list
                result[main_key][key] = value_list
            else:
                result[main_key][key] = value

        else:
            main_key = element
            result[main_key] = {}

    return (result)

new_lines = ['music', ' extension=mp3', '', 'reports/INFOB131', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB131',
             ' max_size=100000', '', 'reports/INFOB132', ' extension=doc,docx,pdf', ' name_contains=INFOB132',
             ' max_size=100000', '', 'games', ' name_contains=SC2,Wesnoth', '', 'pictures/Namur', ' extension=jpeg',
             ' min_size=5000000', ' name_contains=cercle', '', 'pictures/autres', ' extension=jpeg',
             ' min_size=5000000']

print (my_function(new_lines))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code works the only issue I encountered is that I get the code in this order  :

Comment: {'games': {' name_contains': ['SC2', 'Wesnoth']},
 'music': {' extension': 'mp3'},
 'pictures/Namur': {' extension': 'jpeg',
  ' min_size': '5000000',
  ' name_contains': 'cercle'},
 'pictures/autres': {' extension': 'jpeg', ' min_size': '5000000'},
 'reports/INFOB131': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
  ' max_size': '100000',
  ' name_contains': 'INFOB131'},
 'reports/INFOB132': {' extension': ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
  ' max_size': '100000',
  ' name_contains': 'INFOB132'}}