# What is the reason for removing default values of start and step in range() function in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am learning Python3 and as I can see in the past, with Python2, it was possible to create a list of numbers with range() by just passing a single argument, which would be the `last number of list + 1` in the list:

```
range(4) # == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and the `start` and `step` values were defaulted to 0 and 1.

But in Python3 for some reason, it is no longer possible to omit those 2 arguments and for the same result we would need to wrap the range() function with the list() function:

```
range(0, 4, 1) # == range(0, 4)
range(4) # == range(0, 4)
list(range(4)) # == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Question(s):**
What is the reason behind that? Why was the functionality changed this way? Is there a good reason for that?

P.S. or maybe I am doing something incorrectly. Here, I am talking about range() function in general, whether it is being used in for-loops, just to create a list or for any other purpose

Comment: It's nothing to do with which arguments you omit. `range(0,4,1)` and `range(4)` are still equivalent; they just don't produce a list any more.

Comment: The difference of `range` between P2 and P3 is well documented. What specifically is unclear? `range` in P3, as much as `xrange` in P2 takes the same arguments as P2 `range`. They just don't return a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've unfortunately been misled by the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of range:

```
>>> range(4)
range(0, 4)
```

It is actually the same interface, but this is returning a lazily-generated [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) now, as opposed to a list.  You may iterate a range instance to consume the values:

```
>>> list(range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

See [Python range() and zip() object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19777612/674039) for more details about this change.

Comment: Are you seeing `[0, 1, 2, 3]` if you execute `range(0, 4, 1)`?