# Why does print(zip(*A)), give output in the form <zip object at 0x7f8ef0f82b48>, but expected output when doing set(zip(*A))? Note that A is a list

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.6

I do understand this is an object, but can you throw some insights on how it is able to map to different lists?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What did you expect `print(zip(*A))` to print? What do you mean "map to different lists"? for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777612/python-range-and-zip-object-type

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `zip` functions returns a custom iterator object that computes each tuple of items from the sequence it is given lazily. This object has no `__repr__` method, so printing it produces the default `<zip object at <address>>`. The `set` constructor then evaluated the created iterator, creating a set of tuples. Sets do have a `__repr__`, so printing the set will produce the expected output.