# Get only the last element of an iterator in the most Pythonic way

Tags: python, iterator

How do I get the last element of an iterator?  I'm aware that I have to exhaust the iterator and return the last value it produced, so the plain approach would be:

```
def last(it):
    for value in it:
        pass
    return value
```

(You might want to catch the `NameError` and raise something else for empty input, but you get the idea.)

Is there a simpler solution I didn't think of, e. g. using `itertools.islice()` (it doesn't seem to accept negative indexes, though) or something similar?

Comment: you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution could be to use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
*_, last = it
```

---

Example:

```
it = range(10)
*_, last = it
print(last)
# 9
```

Comment: are you sure `range()` returns an iterator and not a list?

Comment: @Gsk `isinstance(range(10), list)`

Comment: Unfortunately it comes close to `list(it)[-1]` which keeps all elements in memory at once as well (your solution stores them briefly in `_`).

Comment: @yatu sorry, wrong wording of the question: [`range()` returns an iterable, not an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803830/why-is-the-range-object-not-an-iterator). I'm just curious, I find your answer interesting

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use

```
list(it)[-1]
```

where `it` is the iterator.

You convert it into a list and get the last element.

Comment: This stores all elements in memory briefly, just to get the last one eventually.

Answer (score 2):

The following is about 26% faster than

```
def last(it):
    for value in it:
        pass
    return value
```

as it does the iteration outside of the interpreter:

```
import collections
def last(iterator):
    return collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=1).pop()
```

This raises IndexError if the deque is empty otherwise it returns the last value.

The idea for this comes from the consume example in the itertools module.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pythonic way but just some other solution. If you are ok to use [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.take_nth). Then you can do the following.

```
from toolz import last

last(it)
```