# How to turn a list of iterators into all possible lists using those iterators

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a list of iterators, such as `l = [range(1), range(2), range(3)]` and each iterator iterates over the possibilities that could be in that slot.

However, I don't know how long the list is going to be.
In this case, to get what I want, I can easily do `[[val1, val2, val3] for val1 in l[0] for val2 in l[1] for val3 in l[2]]`.

I've been looking a lot at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html), and couldn't see anything that matched this pattern.

What function can take in a list of iterators and generate a list of all the possibilities for lists where each value in the list is a value of one of the generators in the slots?

Comment: [`range` is not an interator](https://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/).

Comment: [True.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/if-range-is-a-generator-in-python-3-3-why-can-i-not-call-next-on-a-range) Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing up this question, I realized that there is in fact an itertools function that accomplishes this.

`list(itertools.product(*l))` does the trick.

I figure I'll just post this as a self-answered question in case someone else has similar terminology.