# When should I use iter function?

Tags: python, list, loops

### This code

```
for i in range(100, -1, -1):
   print(i)
```

### Is same as:

```
for i in iter(range(100, -1, -1)):
   print(i)
```

Which print's numbers from a list of 0 .. 100 numbers in descending order.

I know about sentinel attribute which stops once it reaches it, but besides that when should i consider using `iter()` function?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

Comment: Sometimes, you want multiple independent iterators over the same iterable object. A good example can be found in the `grouper`  function in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: @G.Anderson No, my question is not about range(), it is about iter() function, i can do that to a list too. i.e `["aa", "bb", "ccc"]` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for this. `iter()` is good for turning things that *would* be memory-hungry iterables into generators, or for turning non-generator iterables that already exist into objects you can call `next()` on.

But `range()` is already a generator (well, not really, but it behaves very similarly to one and has the same advantages), so there's no benefit in this case.

For that matter, for `for` loops in general, if your iterable already fully exists, there's no point in making an `iter()` out of it - the `for` keyword does that behind-the-scenes already.

Comment: Important note: Despite being lazily evaluated and iterable, [Range is NOT a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/if-range-is-a-generator-in-python-3-3-why-can-i-not-call-next-on-a-range)

Comment: What's a "non-generator iterable"? Something like `range` is an iterable, but not an iterator. `iter(range(...))` returns something of type `range_iterator`, which *is* (as you would expect) an iterator.

Comment: @chepner when I was thinking non-generator iterables I was thinking of iterable data structures, mostly - `list`s, `set`s, `dict`s, etc. for which the memory is already allocated.

Comment: `iter` does not turn an iterable into a generator. A generator is simply one type of iterables, a function that yields. `iter` turns an iterable into an iterator by calling its `__iter__` method. The only reason `iter` is unneeded in the OP's case is because `for` always creates an iterator from the given iterable itself, just like `iter` does, making `iter` redundant.

Comment: "iter() is good for turning things that would be memory-hungry iterables into generators" That is wrong, `iter` returns an iterator from an iterable. Also: "but range() is already a generator (well, not really, but it behaves very similarly to one and has the same advantages" no, it doesn't behave like a generator. It doesn't have a `__next__` method, in particular. It is an *iterable* container, not an *iterator*. `iter` is for when you want an iterator, which may be use for, say, manually iterating over something, or for various other reasons. And you may want one out of a `range`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example. Say I have a list of items, where an item count is followed by that number of items, over and over.

```
[1, 'some data', 3, 'some data', 'some data', 'some data', 2, ...]
```

I might like to iterate over this data using nested `for` loops: the outer loop getting the item count, and the inner loop getting the following `n` elements of the list. The two loops can share an explicit iterator:

```
from itertools import islice

my_data = [1, "a", 3, "b", "c", "d", 2, "e", "f"]
my_iter = iter(my_data)
for i, count in enumerate(my_iter):
    print(f"Round {i}")
    for item in islice(my_iter, count):
        print(f'  {item}')
```

This code produces the output

```
Round 0
  a
Round 1
  b
  c
  d
Round 2
  e
  f
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want an iterator. That is what `iter` is for, it returns an iterator for what you pass to it. So, consider the following generator, which takes advantage of the properties of an iterator, namely, it is single pass and exhaustible, *and extracting an iterator from an iterator should return the iterator itself*, instead of giving you a new one.

```
In [19]: import itertools

In [20]: def chunk_by_n(iterable, n):
    ...:     islice = itertools.islice
    ...:     iterator = iter(iterable)
    ...:     chunk = list(islice(iterator, n))
    ...:     while chunk:
    ...:         yield chunk
    ...:         chunk = list(islice(iterator, n))
    ...:

In [21]: iterable = range(100)

In [22]: chunks = chunk_by_n(iterable, 3)

In [23]: next(chunks)
Out[23]: [0, 1, 2]

In [24]: next(chunks)
Out[24]: [3, 4, 5]

In [25]: next(chunks)
Out[25]: [6, 7, 8]
```

Now, look what happens if we don't make an iterator out of the input:

```
In [26]: def chunk_by_n(iterable, n):
    ...:     islice = itertools.islice
    ...:     #iterator = iter(iterable)
    ...:     iterator = iterable
    ...:     chunk = list(islice(iterator, n))
    ...:     while chunk:
    ...:         yield chunk
    ...:         chunk = list(islice(iterator, n))
    ...:

In [27]: chunks = chunk_by_n(iterable, 3)

In [28]: next(chunks)
Out[28]: [0, 1, 2]

In [29]: next(chunks)
Out[29]: [0, 1, 2]

In [30]: next(chunks)
Out[30]: [0, 1, 2]
```