# What does * do with range() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, sequence

I was doing a Hackerrank python problem the task was to print `123...N` (where `N` is the input)
without using any string function.

Someone commented a solution which is:

```
print(*range(1, int(input())+1), sep='')
```

My question is:

1. What is the use of * here with this range() function?
2. Why we can't do it by only using range() function inside the print?
3. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `python-2.7` seems to be misfit tag here, in fact `print(*range(1, int(input())+1), sep='')` will cause `SyntaxError` if you attempt to use it in 2.7 *(tested in 2.7.17)*

Comment: It's called **unpacking**. You can do it in any iterable, not just range.

Comment: @Daweo It works in Python 2.7 if you use `from __future__ import print_function`. The syntax error arises when the interpreter is expecting `print` to be a statement, in which case the parentheses are part of the expression used by `print`, not to indicate an argument list.

Comment: Refer:https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: VTR - that question is about *parameters*, not *arguments*. That said, this question might still be a duplicate of something.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [asterisk in function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5239856/4518341) (or at least partial duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing this, essentially,

```
n = int(input())
print(*range(1, n + 1), sep='')
```

1.) The [star `*args` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) lets you fill in arguments from an iterable. For example, these are all equivalent:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

foo(1, 2)
lst = [1, 2]
foo(*lst)
tup = (1, 2)
foo(*tup)
```

2.) Certainly you can use just `range` without unpacking `*args`. See next item.

3.) Another way would be to `print` within a `for` loop, or more compactly to create a string `s`:

```
s = "".join(map(str, range(1, n + 1)))
print(s)
```

Comment: Is not `"".join` string function and task requriement *without using any string function*?

Answer (score 7):

The `*` "unpacks" an iterable, so that each element is passed as a separate argument, rather than the function receiving the iterable object as a single argument:

```
>>> print(range(1,3))
range(1, 3)
>>> print(*range(1,3))
1 2
>>> print(1,2)
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

range will give you an iterable, a ready object that when consumed will give you individual values. Try to print it without the * and it will call the object __str__() magic method and print range(start, end).

Putting a star upon calling a function will pull all the values from the iterable and pass them as "comma separated" arguments to the function. That is called unpacking.

Comment: Beside the point, but `range` is not a generator or iterator, though it is an iterable and a sequence. See [If range() is a generator in Python 3.3, why can I not call next() on a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092267/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the correction. I am not as familiar with the python nomenclature as with the .Net platform.

Comment: Welcome. Can't blame you in any case, it's pretty intricate :) Though you've still got "generator" written in one spot. Also ranges don't get consumed per se, just iterated over. I would describe it as working like a list.

Comment: The "consumed" thing was on purpose. By the way, I found Python iterable behavior different than .Net IEnumerable in the sense that once you iterate over it in python, that's it. It's more like IEnumerator. Will fix the other "generator".