# How does range object allow for multiple iterations while generators object do not?

Tags: python, generator

I am wondering about the differences between range and generator in Python.

I have done some research and found some useful answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222099/difference-between-python-xrange-and-generators) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/if-range-is-a-generator-in-python-3-3-why-can-i-not-call-next-on-a-range/13092317#13092317) which explain the differences between these objects, despite the fact that they may return similar things.

One of the differences I wanted to explore is that the range object can be called multiple times while the generator object cannot. To demonstrate this more clearly, to myself, I considered the following code:

```
def my_range(first=0, last=3, step=1):
    number = first
    while number < last:
        yield number
        number+=step

a = range(0,3)
b = my_range()

for i in a:
    print(i)
print("First")
for i in a:
    print(i)
print("Second")
for i in b:
    print(i)
print("Third")
for i in b:
    print(i)
print("Fourth")
```

Which outputs:

```
0
1
2
First
0
1
2
Second
0
1
2
Third
Fourth
```

It is clear to me from this that the generator gets "used up" while range does not. But I am having trouble finding exactly where in the source code (as well as where the source code is itself) this sort of behavior is defined. I am not sure where to start to find and interpret the code that dictates that a range object can be used multiple times, but a generator object cannot.

I would like help with finding and understanding how property like how many times an object can be iterated over is implemented in Python's source code.

Comment: There's a difference between an iterable and an iterator. A generator is a type of iterator (i.e., it can be exhausted), but iterables need not be.

Comment: The entire state of a range object consists of three integers (start, stop, step); it's trivial to keep them around to re-iterate.  The state of a generator, however, is arbitrarily large.

Comment: @erip I see so the range object is an Iterable. And I can convert it into an Iterator by wrapping it with iter()

Comment: @jasonharper What is the meaning of state? Is it some store of the numbers that the object is constructed with? I am interested in this difference as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range object is a plain iterable sequence, while a generator is also an iterator.

The difference between the two is that an iterable is used to generate iterators which store the iteration state. This can be seen if we play around with `range`, its iterators, and `next` a bit.

First, we can see that range is not an iterator if we try to call `next` on it

```py
In [1]: next(range(0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <module>
----> 1 next(range(0))

TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

We can create the iterator ourselves by calling the `iter` builtin, we can see that this gives us a different iterator type when called on our range.

```py
In [2]: iter(range(0))
Out[2]: <range_iterator at 0x28573eabc90>
```

Each of the iterators created by the iterable will store its own iteration state (say, an index into the range object that's incremented every time it's advanced) so we can use them independently

```py
In [3]: range_obj = range(10)

In [4]: iterator_1 = iter(range_obj)

In [5]: iterator_2 = iter(range_obj)

In [6]: [next(iterator_1) for _ in range(5)]  # advance iterator_1 5 times
Out[6]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [7]: next(iterator_2)  # left unchanged, fetches first item from range_obj
Out[7]: 0
```

Python also creates iterators by itself when a for loop is used, which can be seen if we take a look at instructions generator for it

```py
In [8]: dis.dis("for a in b: ...")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 GET_ITER
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 10)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
              8 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, the `GET_ITER` is the same as doing `iter(b)`.

Now with the generator, after creating it by calling the generator function, Python gives you an iterator directly, as there's no iterable object above it to be generated from. Calling the generator function could be seen as calling `iter(...)`, but passing it everything is left up to the user
as arguments to the function instead of fetching the information from an object it was created by.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Numerlor. The last explanation is nice since I was wondering what happened in the for loop as well since range is an Iterable. Is there more information on how to read these instructions behind the functions, I see you are using the dis library. For instance, is there a guide somewhere that tells us that GET_ITER is the same as iter(b)?

Comment: @RichardKYu What the individual codes do from a higher level perspective can be seen in the documentation for the dis module https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-GET_ITER, for what they're actuall doing you can look into cpython's interpreter loop code (e.g. you can find `GET_ITER` for 3.10 [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Python/ceval.c#L3955)) but this is of course in C.

Answer (score -1):

The yield statement suspends function’s execution and sends a value back to the caller, but retains enough state to enable function to resume where it is left off. When resumed, the function continues execution immediately after the last yield run. This allows its code to produce a series of values over time, rather than computing them at once and sending them back like a list.

So the fourth loop will continue your my_range function with number stored from last call = 3

Comment: It looks like you just copied and pasted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/. And worse, it doesn't answer the poster's question.

Comment: why not Mark, yield keyword explained clearly his problem

Comment: Lol, so i misunderstood his question