# Difference in iterating through range vs enumerate

Tags: python, iterator, range, enumerate

```
next(range(2))
```

gives error,

```
TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

but,

```
next(iter(range(2)))
```

works, and gives the output `0`

but,

```
next(enumerate('a'))
```

works, and gives the output

```
(0, 'a')
```

and,

```
next(iter(enumerate('a')))
```

also does the same.

shouldn't both work in a similar way, what is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092267/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `range` object is an iterable that can be used many times. Each time you create an iterator for `range`,you get a new `range_iterator` object that starts from the beginning of the range and is unaffected by other iterators created on the same object.

```
>>> r = range(2)
>>> type(r)
<class 'range'>
>>> type(iter(r))
<class 'range_iterator'>
>>> iter(r) is r
False
```

A `enumerate` object is an iterator. It will iterate through the contained sequence one time. Any new iterators created on the enumeration are in fact the same iterator object and using one affects any other copies you may have.

```
>>> e = enumerate('a')
>>> type(e)
<class 'enumerate'>
>>> type(iter(e))
<class 'enumerate'>
>>> iter(e) is e
True
```

In short, `enumerate` is the same as `range_iterator`, not `range`.