# Tuple in python not understanding the output

Tags: python, loops, tuples

```
x= (i for i in range(3))
print(x)
for j in x:
    print(j)
    for i in x:
        print(i)
```

O/P:
0 1 2

please explain the code i am not able to wrap my head around this code

i expected this code to print 0 1 2 0 1 2 but the solution is 0 1 2

Comment: Hint: *print(type(x))*

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not a tuple.  `x` is a generator.  After you have printed `x`, you have consumed everything from the generator, so it is positioned at the end, and there's nothing left for the `for` statements.  If you need to reuse the data, convert it to a tuple:

```
x = tuple(i for i in range(3))
```

or even

```
x = tuple(range(3))
```

Comment: Note: simply printing `x` itself does not consume the generator. Though, if it had been `print(*x)`

Comment: Or even just `range(3)` in this particular case

Answer (score 2):

x is a generator.
If you want to get `0 1 2 0 1 2` you can use:

```
x= [i for i in range(3)]  # or x = list(range(3))
for i in range(2):
    for num in x:
        print(num)
```

or use the *range* function without creating a list:

```
for i in range(2):
    for num in range(3):
        print(num)
```

Note:
if you create this code

```
for num1 in range(3):
   print(num1)
    for num2 in range(3):
        print(num2)
```

The output will be `0 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 2 0 1 2` and not  `0 1 2 0 1 2`...

Comment: `x= [i for i in range(3)]` should just be `list(rang(3))`

Comment: thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13092317/10787867