# Python What is difference between file iterator and list iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a file iterator

```
with open('test1.txt','r') as f1:
 print(f1.__next__())
```

But if I do the same thing for a list, it doesn't work.

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a1.__next__()
```

So, what is difference between file iterator and list iterator? Do file and list (or tuple, dictionary, etc.) iterators behave differently?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't call the `__next__` method directly, please use the `next` function, eg `next(f1)`. The same goes for most other "magic" methods whose names begin & end with double underscores (aka dunder methods). So use the `len` function, not the `__len__` method, the `str` function, not the `__str__` method, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such file iterator and list iterator.Iterator works on iter objects. List themselves are iterable , but not an iter object, however we can make them iterable.

```
a =[1,2,3,4,5]
a= iter(a)
a.next()
```

All python data types except number can be made iterable.

[Confused with python lists: are they or are they not iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054057/confused-with-python-lists-are-they-or-are-they-not-iterators)